# How to start Playwright test with data from console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test

We have command npx playwright test tests/my-test.spec.js

But how to set data for this test by console?

For example i need to set variables for URL (google.com) and CountOfBlocks (12)

Comment: Use environment variables or process.argv and a package to parse it: you can set `BASE_URL=http://www.google.com npx playwright test tests/my-test.spec.js` and then use it as `process.env.BASE_URL` - is that the sort of configuration you mean?

Comment: Can i keep 3 env variables?

If i set it in console, script use in code process.env.BASE_URL = console BASE_URL

If i start script, script will find process.env.BASE_URL in local folder if it has

And if no console and local .env in folder, script will be finding it in global .env?

Comment: You can keep as many environment variables as you'd like (I think there is a 128kb limit on linux for example though for your use case that shouldn't be easily reachable)